# PhpMyAdmin password_hash not matched from password_verify

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, password-hash

I searched a lot in web and in forum but I didn't find anything similar to my problem.
I have a strange behavior of the function password_hash() used from phpMyAdmin when I manually add a new user.

If I insert the password and select the 'password_hash() PHP function' it produces an hash that then isn't verified from the php login script.
[image]

If instead I crate the password within a test script like this

```
<?php
$a='123456789!';
echo password_hash($a, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

and then I paste the hash into DB value it works.

In addition I made test creating the pasword in localhost environment with a test script (equal to the above one runned in the server) and by adding the value from phpMyAdmin hashing the value.
Copying and pasting both passwords into server's DB  makes the login work.

I also tried this script for testing hash (locally and in the server)

```
<?php
$pwd='123456789!';
$hash_remote = '$2y$10$sRLWZPLAYO0zz1i9xPARpe/hHOPOrZBeXrmTn9y/sewmsNX/dPKvi';
$hash_locale = '$2y$10$j1meOOT0AOpeeqNKcnieFe1ODKng42TmRwEGO.8/gja381WOKOIbu';
$hash_remote_php = '$2y$10$s8wSV3ZL/1yBFwt5nBTZX.PybeY3HG3w2SuCG4DsRY3ricvl8vc/K';
$hash_locale_php = '$2y$10$d8PErNifkli97BPLMDalYOXaQuZI25O.LWdAj4ImEdbBPdbIsogpC';

if (password_verify($pwd,$hash_remote)){
    echo "Remote Hash phpMyAdmin OK".PHP_EOL;
}else{
    echo "Remote Hash phpMyAdmin KO".PHP_EOL;
}

if (password_verify($pwd,$hash_locale)){
    echo "Locale Hash phpMyAdmin OK".PHP_EOL;
}else{
    echo "Locale Hash phpMyAdmin KO".PHP_EOL;
}

if (password_verify($pwd,$hash_remote_php)){
    echo "Remote Hash PHP OK".PHP_EOL;
}else{
    echo "Remote Hash PHP KO".PHP_EOL;
}

if (password_verify($pwd,$hash_locale_php)){
    echo "Locale Hash PHP OK".PHP_EOL;
}else{
    echo "Locale Hash PHP KO".PHP_EOL;
}
```

but result are always the same:

```
Remote Hash phpMyAdmin KO
Locale Hash phpMyAdmin OK
Remote Hash PHP OK
Locale Hash PHP OK
```

At this point I think is some configuration problem/difference, but i can't figure out what it can be.

The versions of the PHP/MariaDB are

LocalHost: PHP 8.0.30 | 10.4.32-MariaDB (windows 11)

ProductionServer: PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14 | 10.6.16-MariaDB (ubuntu 22.04)

Comment: Are you absolutely, 100% positively sure, that you entered _just_ the password in phpMyAdmin - and not perhaps any copy&pasted whitespace at the end, or something like that?

Comment: 100% sure. Make it a lot of times. I discovered it by adding a test user on DB and the password was inserted by copy it from a file. In server and in localhost. Only in Localhost it worked. I'll try again just in case

Comment: I have tested this myself, by entering your password into a PHPMyAdmin database field and selecting the `password_hash()` PHP function as the function to apply, and I cannot reproduce your problem. In other words, the hash from the database works for me.

Comment: it works also for me if i do it from my localhost. that's the funny (not funny) thing

Comment: Yes, I read that. Weird. But problems that aren't reproducible are hard to solve. I did find this [phpmyadmin issue](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/17121). Perhaps it is related to the version of phpmyadmin?